How to modify LibreOffice user settings programmatically?
Is there a official (or at least convenient) API for changing LO's settings?
As part of automated install/update, I want to change user settings (and also LO system settings):
e.g. :

shortcut keys,
toolbars (show/hide/change),
extensions (install *.oxt)
app-specific view settings, e.g. calc
default font
default folders
etc....

Reason:
Automation is required for large scale deployment, and sometimes after update, or as part of other processes.
I prefer a platform-agnostic & version-agnostic solution.  I prefer Python, but open to other ways.
I tried to manipulate the settings file directly, using xml parse or regular expressions.
But either the format changes after updates, or where my scripts collide with LO's inner logic, resulting in unexpected behavior or failure to run LO.

Welcome to StackOverflow! This post Is there a Libreoffice ‘settings file’? seem to answer your question.
Also, you mentioned that you have a script; it would be good to show it in your question.


Is there a official API for changing LO's settings?

Yes, the UNO API provides a way to modify settings, the ConfigurationProvider interface. For example, listing 5.5 of Andrew's macro document shows how set the default font using Basic, and Python-UNO works the same way.
UNO is an interface to the application, so it requires connecting with or running from within an instance of LibreOffice.
On Windows, Python-UNO requires the script to be run with the python distro bundled with LibreOffice. Whereas on Linux, the system python contains the necessary libraries, and they're easy to install if missing.
